# Difference with running a script using source and ./

Tags: linux, unix

So I have a question about running linux scripts: what's the difference with running a script using "source" and using "./". Also what effect does it have on the environment variables?

Comment: For a start `exit` behaves differently

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip